# Returning result of count native query using EntityManager in Java?

Tags: java, integer, entitymanager, classcastexception

I have the following `SQL Query :`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOG where ID = 'SampleId';
```

I am trying to write this in `java` :

```
public int returnCountOfDogTable(String id){

        String sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOG WHERE ID =:id";
        Query query = persistence.entityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        List<Integer> resultList = query.getResultList();
        int result = resultList.get(0);
        return result;
    }
```

However I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can also use `Number` and call `intValue()`:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOG WHERE ID =:id");
query.setParameter("id", 1);
int count = ((Number) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

Answer (score 13):

Make sense to use **Query#getSingleResult** method:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOG WHERE ID =:id");
query.setParameter("id", 1);
int count = ((BigInteger) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply try this:

```
public int returnCountOfDogTable(String id) {
//...
    List<BigDecimal> resultList = query.getResultList();
    BigDecimal result = resultList.get(0);
    return result.toIntValue();
}
```

Comment: ok, and how to then change big decimal back to int in return value?

Comment: perhaps `result.toIntValue()` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

public int getCountQuery(String sql) {
    int resultCount = 0;
    try {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        resultCount = ((Number) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("SQL Error" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return resultCount;
}
```